# How to copy a single column from word to pre-existing excel table using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a table in word that has two columns. I want to copy only the second column into the 2nd column of my pre-existing table in excel. My 'for' loop is working but all the data is getting repeatedly stored in the same cell.How do i store in consecutive cells of the column?

```
Sub copyToExcel()
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim doc As Document
Dim tbl As Table
Dim lstrw As Long, lstcol As Integer
Dim tblrange As Range

Set doc = ThisDocument
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Visible = True
Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ankit\Downloads\challenges.xlsm")
Set xlsheet = xlwb.Worksheets("Challenge #2")

Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
With tbl
 lstrw = .Rows.Count
 lstcol = .Columns.Count
 For x = 2 To lstrw
    Set tblrange = .Cell(x, 2).Range
    tblrange.End = .Cell(lstrow, lstcol).Range.End
    tblrange.Copy
    xlsheet.Paste
 Next x
End With

Set xlapp = Nothing
Set xlwb = Nothing
Set tblrange = Nothing
Set xlsheet = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Something like `xlsheet.Cells(x,3).Value = tblrange.Text` for example

Comment: Hi. That worked well but at the end of each value that was added to excel there is an extra special character(some box). How do i remove that?

Comment: Try `xlsheet.Cells(x,3).Value = Left(tblrange.Text, Len(tblrange.Text)-2)`